# Google sheets query multiple rows+cols to one cell with lookup table

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Cannot figure out how to pull the results of a query with multiple rows and columns into single cells and find their details from my lookup table. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Trying this
=ArrayFormula(
QUERY({
QUERY({A4:A16,TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,B4:C16)}, "SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 WHERE Col1 MATCHES 'Core 1|Core 2|Core 3' LABEL Col1 'Core ID', Col2 'Full Result'")
}, "SELECT Col2 WHERE Col1 = Col1")
)

[Sheet to help](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DpKyQsm88VLT3UugalmSGUsxEuvEMnAtgxGXPLwS170/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

It's always a headache trying to mix `Query` with `ArrayFormula`. They don't go well together.

I arrived at a nice formula, but the catch is that it relies on you sorting your data by Core Item first. You can easily achieve this with:

```
=SORT(A4:C16)
```

For this example, I placed this formula is cell N4. Then your resultant formula is:

```
=ArrayFormula(
{
  "Core ID", "Full Result";
  UNIQUE(FILTER(N4:N,N4:N<>"")),
  SUBSTITUTE(
    TRANSPOSE(
      SPLIT(
        REGEXREPLACE(
          TEXTJOIN(
            ",",
            ,
            UNIQUE(
              TRANSPOSE(
                IF(
                  TRANSPOSE(FILTER(N4:N,N4:N<>""))=FILTER(N4:N,N4:N<>""),
                  FILTER(O4:O,O4:O<>"")&
                  " ("&
                    VLOOKUP(FILTER(O3:O,O3:O<>""),A23:B53,2,)&
                  ") - "&
                  FILTER(P4:P,P4:P<>"")&
                  " ("&
                    VLOOKUP(FILTER(P4:P,P4:P<>""),A23:B53,2,)&
                  ")",
                  ";"
                )
              )
            )
          ),
          ",(;,)+",
          ";"
        ),";"
      )
    ),
    ",",
    CHAR(10)
  )
})
```

It uses the Group Concatenate method I've adopted for stuff like this with `UNIQUE`, `TRANSPOSE`, and `IF`. This can probably be solved without using the precalculated `SORT` by substituting all instances of the `N4:N`, but doing it this way saves on computation time. If you need it gone, you can also hide the column or stow it in another sheet.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok breaking apart your formula then this would be an acceptable approach.

Start by Building your query criteria.

```
=ArrayFormula(
    QUERY({QUERY({A4:A16,ArrayFormula(B4:B16&" ("&VLOOKUP(B4:B16,A23:B53,2,false)&") - 
("&VLOOKUP(C4:C16,A23:B53,2,false)&")")}, "SELECT Col1, Col2 WHERE 
Col1 MATCHES 'Core 1|Core 2|Core 3' LABEL Col1 'Core ID', Col2 'ALL Result'")}, 
"SELECT Col1, Col2 WHERE Col1 = Col1"))
```

Then in another column get the unique values and lastly, join the filtered values.

```
=UNIQUE(E4:E17)

=Join(Char(10),FILTER(F4:F12,E4:E12 = H4))
```

The downside to this is you will need to have multiple columns to achieve your desired result but it is easy to follow. Good luck!